# How to build multiple integration test cases using CommandLineJobRunner in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am running the integration test cases using CommandLineJobRunner of Spring Batch. If I run it one by one then it is running perfectly but when I build it by clean and install it is not moving forward, its stuck in infinite wait.

e.g: Running job.eg.egJobIT....

```
 package job.eg;
    import com.**;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:*.xml"})
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
    @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class EgJobIT {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value="EG_JOB")
        private Job job;

        @Autowired
        private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        private JobRepository jobRepository;

        @Test
        public void launchJob() throws Exception {

            JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

            jobParametersBuilder.addString("legacy.date.format", "yyyyMMdd");

            JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();

            String[] jobParamArr = MapUtil.mapToString(jobParameters);

            String[] contextParam = new String[] { "file:src/test/resources/*.xml", "EG_JOB" };
            String[] args = Stream.of(contextParam, jobParamArr).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);

            final Queue<Integer> exitCode = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);
            CommandLineJobRunner.presetSystemExiter(new SystemExiter() {
                @Override
                public void exit(int status) {
                    exitCode.add(status);
                }
            });
//here it is calling main() method.
            CommandLineJobRunner.main(args);
            Assert.assertEquals(0, exitCode.poll().intValue());
        }
    }
```

N.B:Please consider * mark as some class or config file name.

Comment: Please share more details about your test setup to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like above example, there are more then one Integration test case available and all test cases are calling same as mentioned above.

Comment: thanks, but I can't see from what you shared why it hangs with clean install.

Comment: imagine that there are three integration test cases for three different jobs and if i run individually as JUnit Test, then it is success. But when i build the total project like, Project-->right click-->run  as-->maven clean and maven install, then it is hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a valid reason to use the `CommandLineJobRunner` in a unit test, unless you don't trust the code from Spring Batch.

A typical job unit test uses a `JobLauncher` or `JobLauncherTestUtils` as documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing

So in your case, since you are injecting the job and the job launcher in your test class, you can write something like:

```
@Test
public void launchJob() throws Exception {
   // given
   JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
   jobParametersBuilder.addString("legacy.date.format", "yyyyMMdd");
   JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();

   // when
   JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

   // then
   Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
}
```

Comment: The above solution I already have but my jenkins build is failing with Application.main fails while integration test succeeds. So I came up with this solution to cover main() from the Integration test itself.

Comment: `but my jenkins build is failing with Application.main fails`: I would fix the root cause rather than change my test in an incorrect way. I can try to help if you accept this answer and ask another question about your jenkins issue.